# Laravel socialite dynamic redirectUrl not working in multi-tenant app

Tags: laravel

i have a multi-tenant app and i am trying to add Facebook linking in it i have tried the process using laravel socialite but i have a problem that when i use dynamic redirect url like so

```
 return Socialite::driver('facebook')
        ->with([
            'redirect_uri' => "https://" . $dynamichost . "/social/facebook/callback",
        ])
        ->redirect();
```

or this way

```
return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirectUrl('https://' . $dynamichost . 

'/social/facebook/callback')->redirect();
```

facebook returns error url mismatch. Note i also have set a value for redirect_url in .env
then i have services values like this

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('CALLBACK_URL_FACEBOOK'),
    'default_graph_ve`enter code here`rsion' => 'v3.3',
],
```

my guess is socialite somehow set the redirect url equal to the value which is coming from .env and when i change it dynamically it still thinks that url will be like the value of .env and i have tested this scenario the request get success response if keep the redirect url static.
Any suggestions how can i overcome this. thanks.

Comment: you also need to add the url in facebook accepted url

Comment: yeah i have already added the urls in Valid OAuth Redirect URIs in facebook login settings of the app and tested them still same scenerio for example if i have web.test set in .env and i am making redirect call with static web.test then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it was dumb mistake i had to match the redirect url in callback handling method. its fixed now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use custom redirect-uri dynamic :

```
use Socialite;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider;

$socialite = Socialite::buildProvider(
  FacebookProvider::class, [
    'client_id' => 'your_id',
    'client_secret' => 'your_secret',
    'redirect' => 'url',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3', //not sure if this needed as far as i know, in socialite the version is defined
  ]
)->redirect();
```

Comment: yeah already tried it like but it gives some other error Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given

Comment: $config = [
            'client_id'    => env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'),
            'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'),
            'redirect'     => $dynamicurl
        ];

        return Socialite::buildProvider(\Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider::class, 
      $config);

Comment: did u set $socialite->redirect() ?, it worked just fine for me in my app

Comment: yeah sorry for this mistake but still same error Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you (truncated...)

Comment: that meant your redirect_uri not accepted, not in the whitelist (forgot the name in developer)

Comment: this is the error i am getting for all the attempts i did above

Comment: i have 2 domain to test, added https://domain_a.com/redirect and https://domain_b.com/redirect in the list

Comment: i dont know man, its just from the error message that redirect_uri are not accepted. the code worked for me for dynamic redirect callback